# Spring Boot: Default serialization for java.time.Duration changed from String to Number

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

We upgraded lately from Spring Boot 2.1.9 to 2.2.1 which caused our tests to fail. Investigation led to the result that the `java.time.Duration` type is now serialized differently by default. Instead of having the String `"PT15M"` in the JSON message we now get `"900.0"`. The POJO definition looks like that

```
@JsonProperty(required = true, value = "duration")
@NotNull
private final Duration duration;
```

The question now is if there is some configuration property we can use to get the "old" behavior. I know we could also add annotation

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
```

but I would prefer a way to have it just by configuration.

Comment: have you implemented your own formatter for this?

Comment: 98% sure that's a Jackson serialization flag; there's generic documentation in the Boot properties on how to configure those.

Comment: No own formatter ,if you add the annotation it works out of the box, having it in this format with PT15M

Comment: Good news is, we meanwhile found the property, it is spring.jackson.serialization.write-durations-as-timestamps=false . I was looking directly at spring.jackson and didn't step in the serialization namespace...

Comment: Nevertheless, question is still why the default behavior changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you changed the version of spring-boot from 2.1.9 to 2.2.1  , there is also a change of version for the Jackson. From Spring-boot version 2.2 onwards the Jackson version is changed to 2.10. One of the changes that are part of this Jackson version change is the use of the flag `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DURATIONS_AS_TIMESTAMPS` for serializing the Duration time stamps instead of the earlier `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`.

By adding following property to the application.properties the service (and the serialization feature) will behave like pre 2.2

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-durations-as-timestamps=false
```

Springboot 2.2 [Changelist](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes)

Jackson 2.10 [changelist](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.10)

Jackson [Issue tracker](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/pull/75)

Comment: That's it, we found the property meanwhile as well. Thank you for the details anyways.